# Base url twice with opencart site and admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have uploaded opencart upload folder to http://example.com/opencart folder.

Now when I open it, it is opening, but after cliking any navigation menu (e.g. contact us), 404 error shown and url in address bar is

**http://example.com/example.com/opencart/?route=information/contact**

instead of

**http://example.com/opencart/?route=information/contact**

But when I hover on Link, it is showing perfect url in bottom of browser. (e.g. in above case, on Hover - "http://example.com/opencart/?route=information/contact" is shown...

how to fix it ?

EDIT****

my .htaccess in opencart/ folder :

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]   
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L] 
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please show us your `.htaccess` file. You more than likely need to add a `RewriteBase`.

Comment: @MikeRockett .htaccess file contains RewriteBase /

Comment: The extra `example.com` in the URI after the first `/` suggests a fault in your `RewriteRule`. Please post the .htaccess in the /opencart directory, as well as any .htaccess existing at the site root.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski    .htaccess : RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @darshan Please edit above to add the .htaccess content rather than placing it in the comments.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thnx...question edited and .htaccess added

Comment: @darshan use RewriteBase /  opencart

Comment: please follow this tutorials for turn on seo friendly urls. http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/09/12/how-to-turn-on-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear which version of OpenCart you're running, but in all recent versions there is a comment above the RewriteBase rule in the supplied .htaccess file:

```
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/
RewriteBase /
```

So change it to

```
RewriteBase /opencart/
```